# Find the max element in all the contiguous subarray of size K using only queue

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue

An array  A  and an integer  K are given. We have to find the max element in all the contiguous subarrays of size  K  using **only the queue** in JAVA.

For example:

```
Input:
7 3
12 1 78 90 57 89 56

Output:
78 90 90 90 89
```

How can I solve this using **only queue** in Java?

Comment: an array and an integer are given, ..., solve it using **only the queue**. What queue? What did you try where did you get stuck? Please pick one language

Comment: I can able to solve this with deque...But I'm trying to solve it using Queues only.

Comment: You'll need a function that returns the max element in a given queue. Then you create a queue and fill it with the first K elements of your list. After printing the max (with the help of the initially mentioned function), you discard the first element and add a new one. Repeat until you have no new elements left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Sliding Window` technique to find the maximum element in all the contiguous subarrays of size `K`.
We need to use a `PriorityQueue` for this such that we can retrieve the max element of a particular window in constant time.
First, add all the first `K` elements to queue and return the first max then iterate through the rest of the windows/sub-arrays of size `K` by just adding the new head and removing the tail of the window.
And at each iteration keep returning the `peek` (max) of current window.
Here is an implementation:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = 
new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
 
for (int i=0; i < K; i++)
    queue.add(arr[i]);
 
System.out.println(queue.peek()); // maximum element among first `K` elements
 
// Rest of the windows of size `K`
for (int i=K; i < N; i++)
{
    queue.remove(arr[i - K]); // first element from front
    queue.add(arr[i]);       // adding current element
    System.out.println(queue.peek()); // maximum element in current window
}
```

Comment: Does this require that the integers are unique?

Comment: @Surt No, it will perfectly work with an array with duplicates as well.

Comment: `PriorityQueue.remove(Object o)` takes linear (in queue size) time, that is `O(K)`. It is no better than scanning the window for a max element.

Comment: @user58697 Yes it is `O(N*K)` but please read the question again. OP has strictly mentioned that he wants an approach using **queue** only. From my knowledge this the best time complexity we can achieve if we are using a queue. O(N) is possible if we use a `deque` which he already knows. If you have a more efficient approach using a queue, then please share your idea.